# React Native drawer navigation as part of tab navigation

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement a drawer navigation alongside a tab navigation, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how that would be achieved.

The tab would have 5 items, and should be present on *all* screens. The 5th tab should open a drawer with more menu items.

Clicking on any of the drawer's menu items should of course show those specific screens, but the tab navigation should be still be present.

Comment: Hi @PeteFox, I am trying to achieve the same thing. Did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

In the code below the bottom tab bar (which could be replaced by a top tab navigator) is always present.

The last tab contains the the drawer. It doesn't open by default, but this can be achieved by a this.props.navigation.openDrawer() request.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const buildScreen = name => {
 class Screen extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text>{name}</Text>
       </View>
     );
   }
 }
 return Screen;
}

const DrawerScreen = createDrawerNavigator(
 {
   Child1: buildScreen("DrawerChild 1"),
   Child2: buildScreen("DrawerChild 2"),
 },
 {
   // optional drawer options
   // cfr. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html
 }
);

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
 Tab1: buildScreen("Tab1"),
 Tab2: buildScreen("Tab2"),
 Tab3: buildScreen("Tab3"),
 Tab4: buildScreen("Tab4"),
 DrawerScreen,
});
```

Comment: Interesting solution. But in this case, would the drawer then not have it's own screen? We would want the last button in the tab to only be for opening the drawer, and not actually let it have it's own screen.

Comment: Indeed, the 5th tab is in this case the drawer with it's first child. The drawer is a navigator, so clicking it's menu items would open up other screens, while the tabs below should still be visible, right?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for people still looking for an answer, this is how I implemented mine.

The Drawer Navigation has to be your main navigation. Your tab navigation is nested inside it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function DrawerNavigation() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Home' component={TabNavigation} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default DrawerNavigation;
```

In your Tab Navigation, the tab which you choose to show your Drawer Navigation (in your case the fifth tab) would have a listener prop which fires a function on tabPress, toggling the drawer navigation

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const Home = () => (
    <Text> Hello Home</Text>
);
const Menu = () => {
      return null;
};

function TabNavigation(props) {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen 
                name='Home' 
                component={Home} 
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name='Menu'
                component={Menu}
                listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
                    tabPress: e => {
                      e.preventDefault();                
                      navigation.toggleDrawer();
                    },
                  })}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}

export default TabNavigation;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a stackNavigator with two screens and a materialTabNavigator inside:

```
const SomeStack= createStackNavigator({
  Start: StartStack,
  HomeScreenTab,
}
```

and then:

```
HomeScreenTab: {
        screen: HomeScreenTabTab
    }
```

with:

```
export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: HomeStack,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarAccessibilityLabel: 'Tela Inicial do APP',
                tabBarLabel: ({ tintColor }) => <LabelTitle tintColor={tintColor} 
                              label="Start" />,
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <View style={styles.containerIcon}>
                        <FontAwesome color={tintColor} name="home" size{icons.iconMd} 
                         light />
                    </View>
                ),
            },
        },
        ...SomeOtherTabs
}
```

You put the content of your screens on the screen property and so on.

Comment: Not sure I follow... where would the drawer then go?